# TrueNas Encryption method changed - Is the data safe?

Tags: zfs, encryption, network-attached-storage, truenas

just a quick question of understanding. I have a TrueNas Scale server and I just changed the Encryption method from key to passphrase. Now I wonder if I need to rewrite the whole dataset for this to be applied? Is my data now on disk unencrypted or with the old key?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This is a good question to ask iXSystems/TrueNAS on their forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Any sane disk encryption system has a header that stores the actual Data Encryption Keys, DEK's. That's the key that *actually* encrypts data on disk, and is never seen by the user in normal operation.

The DEK is encrypted using some other method, such as a passphrase or certificate. It can potentially be encrypted multiple times with different methods as well; this is for instance supported by LUKS. The key for the DEK encryption is known as KEK, Key Encryption Key.

ZFS indeed uses this scheme.

When you change method you change how you encrypt the DEK, not the DEK. The change simply reencrypts the DEK with a new KEK. As the DEK is a few hundred bytes at most, this is a cheap operation.

---

In addition KEK's and DEK's should have different properties. The DEK should be a high performing algorithm that is *fast*, so that IO is fast.

The KEK, which may involve low quality user passwords should however be slow, so that guessing keys takes a lot of time, making it even more infeasible. This a key derivation scheme and multiple rounds is commonly used for the KEK - as it only needs to be decrypted once upon boot.